# I can't upload user face template in device (SpeedFace-V4L)

Tags: c#, wpf, zkteco

I am using the ZKteco device (speedFace-V4L) with the ZKFace VX5.8 facial algo.

I want to download and upload the users faces templates, but I can't do it.

If I try to download the face template (from device to software) it works, but the opposite does not work, it downloads all other information without a face template.

I debugged this and found the error code is -103, according to the documentation which means **device send back error of face version error**

[image: Device send back error of face version error]

I tested the official demo with this device, and it still doesn't work!

I'm using `GetUserFaceStr(int dwMachineNumber, string dwEnrollNumber, int dwFaceIndex, ref string TmpData, ref int TmpLength);` function to get user informations and `SetUserFaceStr(int dwMachineNumber, string dwEnrollNumber, int dwFaceIndex, string TmpData, int TmpLength)` to set it

I forgot to say that the functions are working fine with the **MB2000** device.

How can i solve this please.

**Device**: SpeedFace V4L
**Face algo**: ZKFace VX5.8
**SDK**: Standalone SDK-6.3.1.43
**Language**: C#, WPF

Comment: You can try with zkteco api: https://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html . It is a paid service. But you can do using this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem just a few days. We contacted ZKteco support and this the solution:

The **Standalone SDK** is not fully compatible with ZkTeco Visible Light Series devices and you have to contact ZKteco Sales to request the **Push SDK** which is in deed a communication protocol Http based so they will give access to the Api.

The ZkTeco new devices have http server like embeded. Also you have to pay for that **Push SDK**.

But with it you will be able to download user faces and upload user faces to SpeedFace v4L devices via TCP IP.